# Do webdatarocks supports muliple pivot report and chart on dashboard

Tags: angular, pivot-table, dashboard, webdatarocks, flexmonster

Do webdatarocks supports muliple pivot report and chart on dashboard.
I need to load a list of reports,
on first row – report 1 with pivot table and chart  and on row two – report 2 with different data as its chart values and so on.
is it possible to achieve this.

I’m trying this , for me its loading the first chart values or the last one.
on loop every its has the chart container as id

id=”googlechart-container”

or using,

@ViewChild(“#somehtmlref”) child: WebDataRocksPivot; on TS

<wbr-pivot #somehtmlref [toolbar]=”true” [report]=”pivotReport” [width]=”‘100%'” [height]=”400″ [customizeCell]=”onCustomizeCell” (ready)=”onPivotReady(report.reportConfig)”
(reportcomplete)=”onReportComplete($event)” (reportchange)=”onReportChange($event)”>
WebDataRocks will appear here

are those causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple pivots on the page, you should add multiple WebDataRocks instances and multiple charts' containers as well, for example:

```
  <app-wbr-pivot
    #pivot1
    [toolbar]="true"
    [width]="'100%'"
    [height]="500"
    [report]="'https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/reports/report.json'"
    (reportcomplete)="onReportComplete()">
    WebDataRocks will appear here
  </app-wbr-pivot>

  <div id="googlechart-container1"></div>

  <app-wbr-pivot
    #pivot2
    [toolbar]="true"
    [width]="'100%'"
    [height]="500"
    [report]="'https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/reports/report2.json'"
    (reportcomplete)="onReportComplete2()">
    WebDataRocks will appear here
  </app-wbr-pivot>

  <div id="googlechart-container2"></div>
```